# How to enter user's password on remote server within SSH (not SSH password)

Tags: ssh, password, remote-management

I'm pretty sure this question has been already come up not only to me but I just fail to find answer.

So I do ssh connection to a remote server with ssh certificate. No issue so far.

Then I'm doing configuration on the remote server and obviously time to time I need sudo privileges. Thus I need to type password of my user from the remote server.

As far as password is strong its hard to remember it. Actually issue is not to remember but rather how to automate typing it.

Is it where [pass](https://www.passwordstore.org/) can help me? Or some other small linux tool?

I am looking for best practices and Linux way. Not sure I want to rely on heavy and bloat GUI application. But if no other choice...

Thanks.

Comment: Just about any password manager would allow you to transfer your password to the clipboard, allowing you to paste it into the remote session when you need it.

Comment: Yeah, is it the only one way to do so?